Setting up the Opamp Extension with collector using Opamp Supervisor, but getting the below error of BootStrap not Found
Have setuo the opamp server using the https://github.com/open-telemetry/opamp-go and its up and running and same way have started my supervisor using the opampSupervisor from otelcontribmain https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/cmd/opampsupervisor
it has started but getting exited saying the error  could not get bootstrap info from the Collector: collector's OpAMP client never connected to the Supervisor
i could see my Opamp server running on 4320 and the same is configured in the supervisor.yaml file as well, but still getting the error
Have setuo the opamp server using the https://github.com/open-telemetry/opamp-go and its up and running and same way have started my supervisor using the opampSupervisor from otelcontribmain https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/cmd/opampsupervisor
it has started but getting exited saying the error  could not get bootstrap info from the Collector: collector's OpAMP client never connected to the Supervisor
i could see my Opamp server running on 4320 and the same is configured in the supervisor.yaml file as well, but still getting the error
My Expectation is , the opamp server with extension should continue to work with supervisor withour any issues
